# Machine-readable list of abbreviations

Tags: computational-linguistics, online-resources, resource-request

Is there a list of standard abbreviations/acronyms available for computational linguistics tasks? I understand 'standard' is a subjective term here but anything that is not too domain specific(not a list of medical or chemical abbreviations) should be a start for me.

Comment: Abbreviations of what? Abbreviations in dictionaries? :) Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Oxford English Dictionary: List of Abbreviations](http://www.indiana.edu/~letrs/help-services/QuickGuides/oed-abbr.html) is machine readable, and 'standard' too.